# Primefaces Subtable inside another subtable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Can we use a simple subtable inside another subtable?

I tried to use like this, but html is not generated.

I can get this done by using ui:repeat or p:dataGrid, but the issue is that the generated data table must be able to be exported to Excel & PDF with p:dataExporter. That is not supported in primefaces if we use it with anything other than dataTable.

Please help.

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" value="#{storeReportsTransfer.drows}" var="i"  >
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputLabel value="Department Issue Report "/>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{storeReportsTransfer.fromDepartment.name}"/> 
    </f:facet>

    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column headerText="Department" />
            <p:column headerText="Category" />
            <p:column headerText="Item" />
            <p:column headerText="Rate" />
            <p:column headerText="Total" />
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>

    <p:subTable value="#{i.categoryBillRows}" var="cbr" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{i.department.name}" />
        </f:facet>

        <p:column >
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{cbr.category.name}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <p:subTable value="#{cbr.itemBillRows}" var="ibr" >
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{ibr.item.name}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{ibr.bill.netTotal}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{ibr.bill.grantTotal}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:subTable>
        </p:column>

        <p:columnGroup type="footer">
            <p:row>
                <p:column footerText="Totals: " style="text-align:right"/>
                <p:column footerText="#{cbr.bill.netTotal}" />
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>

    </p:subTable>


</p:dataTable>
```